# Using Castor, how do you map Java class "java.util.ArrayList" to element "ArrayList", but also generate elements for the objects that it contains?

Tags: java, mapping, collections, castor

Using Castor, how do you map Java class `java.util.ArrayList` to element `<ArrayList/>` instead of `<array-list/>` while still including the elements that it contains?

For example, the class mapping

```
<class name="java.util.ArrayList">
    <map-to xml="ArrayList" />
</class>
```

maps an `ArrayList` object to an empty  element, omitting elements for the objects that the `ArrayList` may contain.  How do you coerce Castor into also generating elements for those contained objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add attribute `autocomplete="true"` to the mapping:

```
<class name="java.util.ArrayList" auto-complete="true">
    <map-to xml="ArrayList" />
</class>
```

See description of `auto-complete` under Section [`<class/>`](http://www.castor.org/xml-mapping.html#The-%3Cclass%3E-element) in [Castor XML Mapping](http://www.castor.org/xml-mapping.html).

Comment: auto-complete aye - nice one.